# How do you exit a Raspberry Pi terminal? I've tried cltr+c but it doesn't work

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've tried closing a rasberry pi terminal process the same way as any other linux terminal, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: to close a terminal, use `Ctrl` `D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f4</kbd>, that worked for me to exit the process.